# Show loader after changing to next page (navigation bar)

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show the loader after clicking the title on the navigation bar (still on same page), not while waiting for the loader and change the page.

How can I do it?

```
<body>
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link loader" href="/" >
        <i class="mdi mdi-monitor-dashboard menu-icon"></i>
        <span class="menu-title">Dashboard</span>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#sidecodebar- 
            layouts" 
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-controls="sidebar-layouts">
        <i class="mdi mdi-map-marker menu-icon"></i>
        <span class="menu-title">Farm Profile</span>
        <i class="menu-arrow"></i>
      </a>
   <div id="loadermodal" class="modalloader">
  <div class="sk-chase">
    <div class="pixel-loader"></div></div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).on("click", ".loader", function() {
  var myTargetModal = $(this).attr("href");
  $("#loadermodal").hide();
  $("#loadermodal").fadeIn();
  $(myTargetModal).fadeIn();
  return false;
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: This javascript only show the loader after click and change the page.

Comment: Share your HTML too.

Comment: Well, If you make an on click event its waiting for a click.